# Display Port Monitor mappings change at random 14.04

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have a Dell E7240 with Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed the Hardware Enablement Stack and the 3.17 kernel. Now, when I use my docking station, I can get 3 monitor support, and it works great.

The issue is, for whatever reason, whenever I disconnect my laptop and reconnect it to the dock, the monitor mappings change.

For example, I have the following layout:

```
+----+         +----+
|    |+-------+|    |
|  A ||   B   || C  |
|    |+-------+|    |
+----+         +----+
```

The monitors are actually plugged into the docking station VGA slot, Display Port, and DVI Slot, respectively. However, ubuntu recognizes them using DP's probably because the dock is using Multi Streams. When I use xrandr I have the following displays on

```
dp2
dp3
dp4
```

Lets assume dp2 = a, dp3 = b, and dp4 = c.

When I reconnect, now dp3 = b, dp2=c and dp4=a
So now, my layout is all messed up, and I have to manually reconfigure it all over again.

Any idea how I can get Ubuntu to maintain the same consistent layout so I don’t have to manually reconfigure it every single time?

Comment: You could look into installing the `laptop-mode-tools` then looking into the config file for setting a script like with `xrandr` for setting your monitors back when you're docked.  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1849639

Comment: Running a script wont help because the dp2,3,4 stuff is all mapped differently everytime